# How to set the UITableHeight according to the JSON contents?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm relatively new to Swift and development as a whole. So please be kind to me.
I have a `UITableView` that displays `JSON` data from Facebook. It contains the list of pages a user is admin of. I have taken care of displaying the data but I can't resize the table according to the table contents. 
I'm asking because I haven't yet found the solution for my problem through other similar questions.

Comment: Do you want to change the `tableview`'s height?

Comment: Use self size tableView

Answer (score 1):

My TableView

```
@IBOutlet weak var filterTableView: UITableView!
```

When you reload TableView To show data Call `UITableView_Auto_Height` Func 
as I called in DidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        self.filterTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        filterTableView.delegate = self
        filterTableView.dataSource = self
        filterTableView.isScrollEnabled = false

        //here I called the function 
        UITableView_Auto_Height()
        //Reloading TableView
        filterTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Required Function

```
func UITableView_Auto_Height()
    {
        //Check for the content Size 
        if(self.filterTableView.contentSize.height < self.filterTableView.frame.height)
            {

            //if ContentSize is big set the frame 
            var frame: CGRect = self.filterTableView.frame;
            frame.size.height = self.filterTableView.contentSize.height;

            //Assign frame
            self.filterTableView.frame = frame;
        }
    }
```

Call that Required func when you reload Data in TableViews

For cell Automatic dimension you can write just these 2 lines in DidLoad

```
self.filterTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // for assumption
self.filterTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: I actually saw your answer on a similar post before; I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: UITableView_Auto_Height even this didn't helped you ?  Please can you elaborate what exactly output you are getting and what output you are looking for and Some of your UI

Answer (score 0):

To set up your self-sizing cell, just add AutoLayout to your cell, specify your tableView’s estimatedRowHeight, and set the tableView’s rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension (this will be the default setting in future XCode6 versions).

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 49 // estimate height
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** for your table view so that it will take care of cell height as per the content.

But in order to make it work properly ***you need to use proper constraints to your table view cell***.

The automatic dimension will calculate height of your cell based on its constraints from top to bottom so that it can get expected height.

Make sure you have correctly applied constraints to cell subviews.

For reference see [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) and [this](https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Comment: It seems your answer is about tableviewcell but what I need help with is the whole table view. The tableview has a fixed height so when the content is more than the table's size, user will have to scroll instead of the tableview resizing itself according to the content.

Comment: @AsminGhale I think you are not clear about TableView concept. The tableView cells will be reused and their dynamic size is not going to increase size of your tableView. The tableView Height will remain constant and you can scroll the rows.