# What is the best approach to resize rows in a table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What is the best approach to resize rows in a table view as smoothly as possible so that the image contained in the cell preserves its aspect ratio while taking up the whole cell? 
Note: These images are being downloaded in `cellForRowAt` method so their sizes are not known until this point during the application runtime.

UPDATE:
This is the code which configures the TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!

var aspectConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    aspectConstraint = nil
}

func setCellImage(image:UIImage){
    let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height
    aspectConstraint = cellImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: aspect)
    cellImageView.image = image
}
}
```

This is the code for the tableViewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorageUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var imageURLS:[String] = [String]()
var listener:ListenerRegistration?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    listener = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener{
        querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("New data: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified data: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed data: \(diff.document.data())")
            }

            guard let newImageURL = diff.document.data()["imageDownloadURL"] as? String else{
                print("Failed to get image download URL")
                return
            }

            print("downloadURL: \(newImageURL)")
            self.imageURLS.insert(newImageURL, at: 0)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)


        }

    }
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageURLS.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let downloadURL = URL(string: self.imageURLS[indexPath.row])


    if cell.cellImageView.image == nil{
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL!) { (data, _, _) in
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.setCellImage(image:image!)
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: Are image received from your server or any third party server ?

Comment: @surjeet Currently I’m using Firebase Storage

Comment: use  UITableViewAutomaticDimension for tableview height

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180400/6080920

Comment: @iOSGeek That is a very similar question but it seems there they are resizing the entire tableView depending on the content not just he cells rowHeight which is where I am a bit stuck. Excellent answer you gave on that question by the way though.

Comment: if you notice at the end of my answer I wrote two specific lines for cell Differently that make your cell to get automatic height based on content '

Comment: @iOSGeek Ive tried doing something similar with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but I keep on getting the rows set to their default height.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps:

1. Set UITableViewAutomaticDimension for the tableview
2. Set auto layout constraints for the image view to the top and bottom of the cell so that the cell will automatically adjust its height to the height of the image view.
3. Since you are images are downloaded you should reload reload cell on the completion of the image download (I will be able to explain more on this if you can share the code you use to download the images).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added the code to the question and have tried doing something similar but it doesn't size the rows properly and also creates a glitchy loading of new cells.